# Вставка String строки в запрос Vk Sdk

Tags: java, android

```
String s = new String();
s = "asasas";
VKRequest r = new VKRequest("wall.addComment", VKParameters.from("owner_id","-119852848","post_id","4","count","20","sort","desc","text",s));
```

Выдаёт ошибку что не передан параметр text. Если написать просто `"text","asasas"`
то работает. Вопрос. Как в этот запрос вставить String строку s;